# How to identify inverted rows and remove them in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
FID1    FID2    PropIBD
ABC    DEF  0.5000
DEF    ABC  0.0000
GHI   LMO  0.002
LMO   GHI   0
L454   9G09 0
```

How can I remove the rows from this dataframe which are duplicated/inverted and with 0 at the PropIBD column?

To give you an example, the first two rows are duplicated, as FID1 of the first row is equal to FID2 of the second, and FID2 of the first row is equal to FID1 of the second. Therefore, I would like to have the following final dataframe:

```
 FID1    FID2    PropIBD
    ABC    DEF  0.5000
    GHI   LMO  0.002
    L454  9G09 0
```

How can I do it in R?

Comment: Are inverted rows always immediately after their corresponding row, as in your example? Otherwise, if both “versions” of the row have a value of 0, which one should be kept?

Comment: Also, is it possible for one case’s `FID2` to be another valid case’s `FID1`, or vice versa, when it’s not an “inversion”?

Comment: I might expand your example a bit to include these kinds of complications if they apply.

Comment: no the inverted rows are not necessarily immediately after their corresponding row. In general, if they are inverted, one of the two will have always a value different from 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update

With base R, you can use `ave` + `pmin/pmax`, e.g.,

```
> transform(df, PropIBD = ave(PropIBD, pmin(FID1, FID2), pmax(FID1, FID2), FUN = sum))
  FID1 FID2 PropIBD
1  ABC  DEF   0.500
2  DEF  ABC   0.500
3  GHI  LMO   0.002
4  LMO  GHI   0.002
5 L454 9G09   0.000
```

## Previous

You can use `aggregate` + `pmin/pmax`

```
aggregate(
    PropIBD ~ .,
    transform(
        df,
        # for each row, the "smaller" string is put in `FID1` (sorted by alphabetical order), while the "larger" will be put in `FID2`
        FID1 = pmin(FID1, FID2), 
        FID2 = pmax(FID1, FID2) 
    ),
    max
)
```

which gives

```
  FID1 FID2 PropIBD
1  ABC  DEF   0.500
2 9G09 L454   0.000
3  GHI  LMO   0.002
```

---

If you care about the order of elements in `FID1/FID2`, you can use `igraph`

```
library(igraph)
df %>%
    graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>%
    simplify(edge.attr.comb = "max") %>%
    as_data_frame() %>%
    setNames(names(df))
```

which gives

```
  FID1 FID2 PropIBD
1  ABC  DEF   0.500
2  GHI  LMO   0.002
3 L454 9G09   0.000
```

Comment: Would you please explain the logic of this code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many thanks! But if I would like not to remove the inverted rows with 0 at the PropIBD, but I would like to replace 0 with the value different from 0 of the original row, I could do it?

Comment: @zephryl yes, you are right that is an issue. I provided another solution using `igraph`, and I hope it resolves the problem.

Comment: @Dan yes, see the comment in the code

Comment: @Khaleesi95 could you elaborate on it?

Comment: In this case, I would like to have a final dataframe like the following one:

df <- data.frame(
  FID1 = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "LMO", "L454"),
  FID2 = c("DEF", "ABC", "LMO", "GHI", "9G09"),
  PropIBD = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.002, 0.002, 0)
)